# Merging multiple observables preserving old values

Tags: angular, rxjs

Hey I am requesting data from an Graphql api. The service is delivering batches in the size of 10 items per batch. My Data is Date based so currently i want to download all data for a month and if some button is clicked load the next one. My approach worked fine for one month where i watch for the next token in the response, but if i try to merge my new date with the old one (merging the obserable) i only receive the new data.

currently i also need to resubscribe when i want to receive new data.

my service code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { TrainingSession, TrainingSessionConnection } from '../shared/interfaces/trainingsession';
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject, of, from, EMPTY, Subject, merge, zip, empty, combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
import { expand, scan, map, shareReplay, mergeMap, combineAll } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AmplifyService } from 'aws-amplify-angular';
import { APIService, SessionByMyGoalQuery } from '../API.service';
import { startOfMonth, endOfMonth, format } from 'date-fns';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class TrainingFacadeService {
    private sessions$: Observable<TrainingSessionConnection[]> = EMPTY;

    // TODO: Caching implementieren

    constructor(private amplifyService: AmplifyService, private apiService: APIService) {}

    private loadPage(index: string, userID: string, startDate): Observable<SessionByMyGoalQuery> {
        return from(
            this.apiService.SessionByMyGoal(
                userID,
                {
                    between: [
                        { date: format(startOfMonth(startDate), 'yyyy-MM-dd') },
                        { date: format(endOfMonth(startDate), 'yyyy-MM-dd') },
                    ],
                },
                null,
                null,
                index
            )
        );
    }
    /**
     * Groups an array of sessions by date this is useful for our stacked cards so a cardstack just gets an grouped array by date
     *
     */
    private groupByDate(sessionArray): TrainingSessionConnection[] {
        const sessionMap = new Map(sessionArray.map(({ date }) => [date, { date, items: [] }]));
        sessionArray.forEach(session => {
            (sessionMap.get(session.date) as TrainingSessionConnection).items.push(session);
        });
        const result: TrainingSessionConnection[] = (Array.from(
            sessionMap.values()
        ) as unknown) as TrainingSessionConnection[];
        return result;
    }

    loadAllSessions(startIdx = null, userID: string, date: Subject<Date>): Observable<TrainingSessionConnection[]> {
        // if (!this.sessions$) {
        //  this.sessions$ = this.requestSessions(startIdx, userID).pipe(shareReplay(1));
        // }
        date.subscribe(currentDate => {
            console.log('called');
            // this.sessions$ = this.requestSessions(startIdx, userID, currentDate).pipe(shareReplay(1));

            this.sessions$ = merge(this.sessions$, this.requestSessions(startIdx, userID, currentDate));
        });

        return this.sessions$;
    }

    private requestSessions(startIdx = null, userID: string, date) {
        return this.loadPage(startIdx, userID, date).pipe(
            // take each session and if there is a nexttoken trigger the next request this is because the api returns 10 items max
            expand(sessions => {
                return sessions.nextToken ? this.loadPage(sessions.nextToken, userID, date) : EMPTY;
            }),
            // map each response to our ConnectionModel because the items arent grouped
            map(sessions => {
                return this.groupByDate(sessions.items);
            }),
            scan((all, current) => {
                return [...all, ...current];
            }),
            shareReplay(1)
        );
    }
}
```

my Component Code

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { TrainDataService } from './traindata.service';
import { MatDatepicker } from '@angular/material';
import { APIService, SessionByMyGoalQuery } from '../API.service';
import { AmplifyService } from 'aws-amplify-angular';
import { TrainingSessionConnection, TrainingSession } from '../shared/interfaces/trainingsession';
import { TrainingFacadeService } from './training-facade.service';
import { scan, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, Subject, BehaviorSubject, EMPTY } from 'rxjs';
import { addDays, subDays, setDate } from 'date-fns';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss'],
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(
        public trainDataService: TrainDataService,
        private apiService: APIService,
        private amplifyService: AmplifyService,
        private trainingFacade: TrainingFacadeService
    ) {}

    sessions: Observable<TrainingSessionConnection[]> = EMPTY;
    date: BehaviorSubject<Date> = new BehaviorSubject(new Date('2019-01-05'));

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getBatch(null);
    }

    getBatch(offset: string) {
        this.amplifyService
            .auth()
            .currentAuthenticatedUser()
            .then(user => {
                this.sessions = this.trainingFacade.loadAllSessions(null, user.attributes.sub, this.date).pipe(
                    scan((all, current) => {
                        console.log(all);
                        console.log(current);
                        return [...all, ...current];
                    })
                );
            });
    }

    fetchNextMonth() {
        this.date.next(addDays(this.date.value, 31));
        this.amplifyService
            .auth()
            .currentAuthenticatedUser()
            .then(user => {
                this.sessions = this.trainingFacade.loadAllSessions(null, user.attributes.sub, this.date);
            });
    }

    fetchPreviousMonth() {
        this.date.next(subDays(this.date.value, 31));
        this.amplifyService
            .auth()
            .currentAuthenticatedUser()
            .then(user => {
                this.sessions = this.trainingFacade.loadAllSessions(null, user.attributes.sub, this.date);
            });
    }
}
```

My wanted behavior would include that the component can trigger new requests by modifying the date observable. Because it once subscribed to the data it gets all new data and keeps the old.

Comment: This.apiService.SessionByMyGoal returns a promise ???

Comment: yes it does. :)